# ycsb remote test hbase,java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Tags: hbase, ycsb

when I use ycsb to test hbase remotely, I got the well-known warning "java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs" ,But I don't know how to solve the problem.
who can give me some advices?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this warning too, but YCSB still worked correctly.
Make sure your YCSB command is right. I searched the question because YCSB didn't work when I forgot to specify the 'columfamily'.
I used the command below:

```
bin/ycsb load hbase10 -P workloads/workloada -cp /usr/local/hbase/conf -p table=usertable -p columnfamily=family
```